# Last 30 days Data Not Able to Include Previous Year Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

while working on my weekly report, I've encountered an issue for the first time. I suspect that the function used to measure 'last 30 days' is unable to include data from the previous year as we enter the new year. I observed this when changing the 'Data As of' date to a more later date and seeing that it only includes 'Last 7 days' of the current year. I would like the function to include data from the previous year as of January, and I believe this issue will no longer be present in February.

[image]

this is the measure created for number of open cases in the last 30 days, if it helps

[image]

I tried using the "DATESINPERIOD" function but still obtain the same error.

Comment: Paste code as text and not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEADD` only returns dates that are in the range of the given column. Since you are using
`.[Date]` you are/referencing the hidden date table that is created when using `Auto date/time` under the Time intelligence setting under Options, and this hidden table is always the full year (1 Jan to 31 Dec).

If your `Data as of` table has dates from last year, then you should drop `.[Date]`.

```
Last 30 days = DATEADD('Data as of'[Data as of], -29, DAY)
```

Or simply just have:

```
Last 30 days = [Data as of] - 29
```

Or even drop the Calculated Columns altogether, and in your Measure just have:

```
Open Cases (in the last 30 days) = 
  var endDate = MIN('Data as of'[Data as of])
  var startDate = endDate - 29
  var casesCount =
    CALCULATE(
      [TOTAL Cases],
      startDate <= 'Cases'[Created date] && 'Cases'[Created date] <= endDate 
    )
  RETURN COALESCE( casesCount , 0 )
```

Comment: Solved, used the Measure and it works now. Thank you.